# How do I ensure that an object's deeply nested members will keep the changes made to it?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a bunch of Java beans objects.

A GOAL has:
An `ObservableList<Objective>.`

An OBJECTIVE has:
An `ObservableList<Strategy>.`

A STRATEGY has:
An `ObservableList<Tactic>.`

A TACTIC has:
An `ObservableList<Task>.`

My program lets the user go down many levels, adding, editing, or removing any of the above items mentioned. If a user selects a certain goal, they may define and add an objective to it. And so on all the way down to tactic.

The problem is, how do I ensure the lowest level changes persist in the levels above? Say you want to add an Objective to Goal 1. Do I pass in Goal 1's ObservableList? From within the "Define New Objective for Goal 1" screen, I can add a new Goal() to this ObservableList. However, Java always passes by value (and not reference), does it not? The moment I close and reopen the Goal Records screen, that Goal's Objectives list is wiped clean and is no longer there.

How do I ensure that the changes will say?

Comment: While it's true that Java is strictly pass-by-value, most of the time the value it's passing is an object reference.  See http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: So like, a C++ "pointer" that points to that object in the heap?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with C++ to answer that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java passes basic types by value (int, char) and Objects by references. Thus you can modify an object passed to method and change will persist.

Example:

```
public class ByReference {

    static class Foo {

        public int i = 0;
    }

    static void changeFoo(Foo fooParam) {
        fooParam.i = 1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo.i); // prints 0
        changeFoo(foo); // pass foo to method by reference
        System.out.println(foo.i); // prints 1 -- change persist
    }
}
```

There is nice article explaining that: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html